# Problem changing scrollbar design in iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using iframe on my site. Now I want to make the scroll on the right side of the iframe invisible. I've searched the whole internet but all the codes I've found don't work.

This is my iframe

```
<iframe src="../pages.php" width="100%" height="650px" class="gitartik"></iframe>
```

last piece of code I tried

```
.gitartik{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.gitartik::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS of the parent frame cannot affect an iframe, you have to include it in the source of the page loaded by the iframe.

JavaScript of the parent frame can add CSS to the page in the iframe, if both pages come from the same origin (which seems to be the case in your example).

Answer (score 0):

To do so First of all remove this part below from the code

```
.gitartik::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
}
```

Then go to your html and find the iframe for example:

```
<iframe src="exampleisfake.co.in">
```

Then edit the iframe tag as shown below:

```
<iframe src="exampleisfake.co.in" scrolling=no>
```

add just like shown above:

```
scrolling=no
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `scrolling` attribute is deprecated and may stop working on new browsers.